# Rendering large tile dataset

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, gdal, r-leaflet

I have spent considerable time troubleshooting this problem on SO but haven't been able to find a suitable answer. In short, I cannot view locally stored map tiles using `R Shiny` and `leaflet`.

I have used [gdal2tiles.py](https://gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) to create a nested directory of tiles from an original high-resolution .tif file projected in [EPSG:27700](https://epsg.io/27700). The output of the tiling process can be viewed with the function's auto-generated .html files (i.e. googlemaps.html, leaflet.html, openlayers.html; see below for a link to a GitHub repo with the tiles and leaflet.html for viewing). I've therefore concluded that gdal2tiles.py is correctly generating the tiles which can be displayed in a browser.

The problem comes when attempting to use `leaflet` and `R Shiny`. I have followed the following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722157/render-custom-tiles-in-r-leaflet-from-local-directory-i-e-not-from-a-git-repos) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620176/how-to-render-custom-map-tiles-created-with-gdal2tiles-in-leaflet-for-r) to point `leaflet` to my local tiles but nothing is displayed either within R Studio's viewer or my browser. It's frustrating because there are no errors printed to the R console when running the code. The code I am using, based on the previous SO answers I have just linked to looks like:

```
library(leaflet)
addResourcePath("mytiles", "C:/path/to/my/tiles/")

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles(urlTemplate = "mytiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png") %>% 
  addMouseCoordinates()
```

The folders and files are named correctly as per the syntax `{z}/{x}/{y}` e.g. the directory structure looks like: `path/to/my/files/6/30/42.png`. I have also uploaded my files to GitHub and passed the repo URL to `urlTemplate` but to no avail. If it helps anyone, the tiles I am using can be found [here](https://github.com/simon-tarr/forest_tiles). The repo is rather hefty in terms of the numbers of files and folders (the input raster is at 25m resolution and I require plenty of zoom levels), but not in size.

I have noticed--when zooming into my tiles in leaflet.html--that there are multiple shades of grey. This is weird because the input .tif was binary; either forest is present (1) or absent (NoData or NA). I have included a screenshot and wonder if this is a rendering problem within Chrome or whether this is causing the tiles to not show in `Shiny`. The screenshot can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE0Nb.jpg).

Could someone please help me display my tiles within R Shiny using local files? I will accept an answer if the best solution is to to GitHub-hosted tiles but my preference is to display locally-stored files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution from the package's [Github repo](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet) issues page. For anyone who may experience issues in the future, it turns out that the flag `tms=TRUE` is required in `tileOptions`. I thank [Barret Schloerke](https://github.com/schloerke) for his help with this. His full (working) code is copied below and can be found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/619#issuecomment-490082162) on Github.

```
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(mapview)

leaflet() %>%
  addMouseCoordinates() %>%

  # Set high zoom level as I have only created tiles at zoom level 6 for a quick example. If you can get this to display, it'll be tough to discern as it's quite zoomed out!

  # This should center the view somewhere over the UK where my tiles have been created  
  setView(0, 51.5135085, zoom = 6) %>%
  # Added toner provider tiles as the white background makes it easier to see my custom tiles
  addProviderTiles(group = "Toner", providers$Stamen.Toner) %>%
  addTiles(group="test", urlTemplate = "https://simon-tarr.github.io/tilestest/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
           options = tileOptions(tms = TRUE, minZoom = 6, maxZoom = 6)) %>% 
  addLayersControl(
    overlayGroups = c("test"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)

  )
```