# Saving and reloading leaflet renders

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

I know this strays from the preferred "here is my code, here is the specific bug" format of Stack Overflow, but I am trying to be as specific as I can with the knowledge that I have at the moment.

I have some rather larger (~500mb) geoTIFF files that I would like to display on a shiny dashboard. I would like to preserve as much of the original information as possible, without making it agonizingly and prohibitively slow. I was wondering if there was a way to save the rendered map and reload it, instead of having the map be regenerated each time the script was run--this data is static enough that there is no point in re-rendering it multiple times.

Here is a brief demo:

```
library(leafem)
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
   addTiles()%>%
      leafem::addGeotiff(
         file="map.tif",
      )
```

Ultimately, the `leafem::addGeotiff()` term could just as easily be `addRasterImage()` if it is possible to save the render, but I have found it to be faster at the moment.

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever sees this question in the future, I wanted to link the solution I ended up going with: [How to render custom map tiles created with gdal2tiles in Leaflet for R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41620176/how-to-render-custom-map-tiles-created-with-gdal2tiles-in-leaflet-for-r).
The solution is ultimately to use the `gdal2tiles.py` script to convert the .tif image to png tiles that can be loaded onto the map in the same way as the basemap.