# Own map in the google maps API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

for my project I wanted to make a navigation system for shops. The main problem I encountered is how to insert my own made map into the HTML/Javascript.

I figured I would just use the google maps API overlay feature. I just don't know where to start, I tried to research it but I just couldn't find any example or tutorial. Maybe one of you could push me in the right direction? An complete answer would be nice, but just research ideas or tutorials are cool to!

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on SO, but I'm pretty sure you are looking for a custom  [TileLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638969/using-custom-map-image-tiles-in-leafletjs) (I don't think you can change the tilelayer of Google maps tho)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.